# Why Assembly.LoadFrom behaves different?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, system.reflection

I have this code running on .NET Framework 4.7.2:

```
static void Test()
{
    Console.WriteLine("--1--");
    LogAllLoadedAssemblies();

    Console.WriteLine("--2--");
    var loaded = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:/MyLib/1_1_0/MyLib.dll");
    Console.WriteLine(AssemblyToString(loaded));

    Console.WriteLine("--3--");
    LogAllLoadedAssemblies();
}

static void LogAllLoadedAssemblies()
{
    foreach(var str in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(AssemblyToString))
        Console.WriteLine(str);
}

static string AssemblyToString(Assembly a)
{
    return $"{a.FullName}, loc: {a.Location}, ctxt:{a.HostContext}";
}
```

When method `Test` is running, i got 2 different results on my PC (Windows) & on TeamCity build agent (Mac OS X):

My **PC (Windows)**:

```
--1--
MyLib, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, loc: C:\MyLib\2_2_0\MyLib.dll, ctxt:0
--2--
MyLib, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, loc: C:\MyLib\1_1_0\MyLib.dll, ctxt:0
--3--
MyLib, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, loc: C:\MyLib\2_2_0\MyLib.dll, ctxt:0
MyLib, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, loc: C:\MyLib\1_1_0\MyLib.dll, ctxt:0
```

**TeamCity build agent (Mac OS X)**:

```
--1--
MyLib, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, loc: C:\MyLib\2_2_0\MyLib.dll, ctxt:0
--2--
MyLib, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, loc: C:\MyLib\2_2_0\MyLib.dll, ctxt:0
--3--
MyLib, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, loc: C:\MyLib\2_2_0\MyLib.dll, ctxt:0
```

So, in 1st case `LoadForm` really loads assembly, I asked, regardless of the fact that the 2.2.0 ver. of this library has already been loaded.

In 2nd case it ignored my query & gave me the assembly already loaded.
Why the behaviour is different?

What I did on the way of attempt to figure out what the cause of this difference:

I found [[here]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=net-5.0#System_Reflection_Assembly_LoadFrom_System_String_):

> The LoadFrom method has the following disadvantages. Consider using Load instead.
>
> - If an assembly with the same identity is already loaded, LoadFrom returns the loaded assembly even if a different path was specified.

*// what "identity" means here?* **UPD:** comments said "*identity*" means an assembly *name, version, culture & public-key-token*

But why on my PC (1st case) this rule does not work?

I've red about some possible different contexts of loaded assemblies. But I see, that `.HostContext` of all assemblies I've ever seen at `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` is always `0`. So, no matter what "*context*" is stands for, looks like it's the same for all assemblies in both cases, and probably it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: You seem to pass a **directory** path to **Assembly.LoadFrom**, not the DLL file path. So a simple explanation would be that in the Team City MacOS X environment the dll stored in that directory has the same identity (i.e. name and version) as the already loaded assembly i.e "MyLib 2.2.0.0".

Comment: Sorry. Thank you. My mistake while shortened my code to concise problem representation. I've fixed question. It is *file* path.

Comment: @lidqy, thank you also for explanation, what is "identity"!

Comment: There's an [issue in the current .NET (Core)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40138), which documents a very weird behavior of .NET ignoring paths in `LoadFrom` when the DLL is _bundled_ with the main executable. Just to be sure about your case: 1) does the TC build _agent_ really runs on MacOS, 2) are you sure there is a “C:\MyLib” _on a MacOS_, 3) any chance it's not being built as .NET 4.7.2 but rather as .NET (Core) and the issue I've linked to might be relevant?

Comment: @user1234567 Identity for an assembly is - **I think**, not 100% sure -  identical AssemblyName. Consists of the name itself, the version, the culture and the public key token.

Comment: @OndrejTucny, thank you for your comment. 3) my application consist of .dll file and .exe file using it. Target framework of both projects is `.NetFramework 4.7.2`. 1) .exe is really runned on Mac OS X by mono (command line instruction, that running it begins with `mono`). 2) paths is not namely “C:\MyLib”, (they are rather relative), but, yes, I'm totally sure, paths in both cases are correct.

Comment: @lidqy, looks like yes: as [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/may/understanding-the-clr-binder#id0400031) says: "_A fully qualified assembly identity consists of four fields: the simple name of the assembly, the version, the culture, and the public key token._"

Comment: It is behavior of .NETCore, different from .NETFramework.  It silently accepts an assembly with a higher version number.  The latter requires an exact match.  You can use LoadFile() instead.